# Redirect STDOUT using _pipe non block

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++

As the title says Im trying to redirect stdout, to test I have the following program:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 4096 

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int fdStdOutPipe[2];
    int fdStdOut;

    printf("Console Print...\n");

    // Start
    fflush(stdout);
    _pipe(fdStdOutPipe, BUFFER_SIZE, O_RAW);
    fdStdOut = _dup(_fileno(stdout));
    _dup2(fdStdOutPipe[1], _fileno(stdout));
    setvbuf( stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );
    fdStdOut = _dup(_fileno(stdout));

    printf("Buffer Print...\n");

    char buffer[ BUFFER_SIZE ] = "";

    while( _read( fdStdOutPipe[0], buffer, BUFFER_SIZE ) )
    {
        // Test
        int l = strlen( buffer );
        buffer[ 0 ] = 0;
    }


    // Close
    _dup2(fdStdOut, _fileno(stdout));
    _close(fdStdOut);
    _close(fdStdOutPipe[0]);
    _close(fdStdOutPipe[1]);

    printf("Console Print Again...\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The issue that Im having is that after that _read is blocking if the stdout pipe is empty...  I was under the impression that pipes are non block by default. Is there any way that I can make the pipe in the example above non block?

Comment: you should try pipes with fork IMO .. Will try to give an example to guide you

Comment: you are using visual c++ am I correct ?

Comment: #include <windows.h> ... yes ;)

Comment: my bad :) actually pipes are awesome with linux IMO [dup2, fork, execl]..hope some one would help

Comment: Agreed... I got the unix equivalent of the code above working on Linux,OSX, iOS and Android... Only the windows port of the function is causing me headaches ;)

Comment: Try using [`PeekNamedPipe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365779%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in conjunction with [`_getosfhandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ks2530z6%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)?

Comment: Any concrete example to demonstrate this approach?

Comment: @McBob any solution found? I'm in the exact same position with working code for linux but not the windows port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before calling _read(), check the pipe status can solve the problem. I'm using this code on VC++ and works fine.

```
struct _stat st;
if(_fstat(fdStdOutPipe[0], &st)) {
    // do error handling
}
if (st.st_size) {
    // data is available to read
    while(_read(...)) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. [The MSVC documentation for `_stat()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stat-functions?view=vs-2019#return-value) does not state that the `st_size` field represents the number of bytes available to be read from a pipe. The closest thing is "If `path` refers to a device, the `st_size`, various time fields, `st_dev`, and `st_rdev` fields in the _stat structure are meaningless." This could be an undocumented feature, or your code is working simply because the `st_size` field is non-zero because your `struct _stat st` is uninitialized and non-zero.

Comment: (cont) If your code still works after you `memset()` the `struct _stat sb` to all zeros, it's an undocumented feature.